# merge results from multiple select statements on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two select statements

```
SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$Uname'
```

and

```
SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address='$email'
```

What statement can I use so I get all results at once i.e

username  as result[0], password as result[1] and email_address as result[2]

To explain better.

I want to check if there is already a record of the username in my database if so then grab the password and then also check if the password there is a record of the email_address as well to ensure users are no allowed to have duplicate usernames or email addresses.

Comment: Unless you're using proper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you're praying that your users never type in anything that could be interpreted as SQL. Code like this should **never** go into production.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: An email of `lol@gmail.com'); drop table users; --` could kill your app, or for that matter, any email which happens to contain `'`. You **absolutely must** escape *any and all* user-provided data that goes into your SQL statements. If you're using PHP, use PDO or `mysqli`. **NEVER** use `mysql_query`. It's extremely dangerous. Use placeholders for every bit of user data and you will not have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an "or" condition:

```
SELECT username, password, email_address 
FROM users
WHERE username='$Uname' or email_address='$email'
```

You can check if the email is there using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT username, password, email_address
       (select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'SHARED' else 'UNIQUE' end)
        from users u2
        where u.email_address = u2.email_address and
              u.username <> u2.user_name
      ) as SharedOrUnique
FROM users u
WHERE username='$Uname' or email_address='$email'
```

Comment: I think this is closer to what I'm looking for but I want to grab the username and password for that username and then just run a check to see if that email address already exists in my database.

Comment: I'm confused . . . where does the email address come from?  Isn't it already in the record for the user?  Do you mean, whether or not the email address is on another record?

Answer (score 1):

> A union query combines the results of multiple select queries.

```
SELECT name, price, warranty_available, exclusive_offer
FROM Products
UNION ALL
SELECT name, price, guarantee_available, exclusive_offer
FROM Services;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the e-mail adres (second statement variable), then why would you want your statement to return it again?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're attempting to do but...

```
SELECT u1.username, u1.password, u2.email_address 
from users u1, users u2
where u1.username='$UName'
and u2.email_address == '$email'
```

Given that your second query is just going to return the value you pass in....

```
SELECT username, password, '$email' as email_address FROM users WHERE username='$Uname'
```

Comment: It's for a registration page so I want to check if both the username and email address already exist on the database

Comment: What do you mean by u1 and u2?